# Give some administrator rights to normal user while still having parental controls

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7 Professional, I want to give a normal user some Administrator rights, like to install/uninstall programs and enable/disable network adapters, while also making it possible to enforce parental controls on that user. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: It used to be that Windows had a Power Users group that could do that, without full admin rights. The problem was that you could exploit it to get the elevated rights anyways. So they took it away.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing this computer with another person then it will be really difficult enforce. Especially if you are using Windows 7 Home Premium as there is no group policies that you can edit there. Also, if you are using Content Advisor in Internet Explorer then user can always install another browser that will bypass it. I would then consider using some parental control system at the home router or some proxy. In case of Windows 7 Home Premium you can still play with windows permissions to folders and files (make some areas of the system read&execute only). However, if you are dealing with advanced user then that person will probably quickly change your settings.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Professional, if that changes anything.